# How to handle Score and Value arrays in F#

Tags: arrays, f#

I have two arrays: Value and Score. The Score array gives a rating for each item in the Value array. What is the "proper" FP way to get the value corresponding to the highest score. I know how to get the max score but another post suggests that getting the corresponding index is not proper FP.

Comment: I'm not sure it isn't "proper FP" -- we do have, after all, `Array.findIndex` and `Array.tryFindIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip both arrays and then apply a maxBy function:

```
let value = [| 4; 3; 8; 2|]
let score = [|35;25;60;20|]

let valScore = Array.zip value score
let maxScore = Array.maxBy snd valScore
let result   = fst maxScore
```

Of course you can do all operations in one step if you are only interested in the final result and you can use Seq if the arrays are huge:

```
let result = Seq.zip value score |> Seq.maxBy snd |> fst
```